# jquery validation on select with message

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I want to add validation on a select statement when someone tries to submit where the select still shows "Please select a timezone":

```
<form id="timezoneform" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>" method="POST">

    <select name="DropDownTimezone" id="DropDownTimezone" class="required">
      <option selected="" name="timezone_selector" value="" style="font-style:italic">Please select a timezone</option>
      <option value="Pacific/Midway">Pacific/Midway (GMT -11:00)</option>
      ....
      </select>
    <input type="submit" id="changetimezone" name="changetimezone" value="Change timezone" />
</form>
```

I tried to provide the same validation that I use for text boxes but I guess it's not the same:

```
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var js = jQuery.noConflict();
js("#changetimezone").click(function() {
js("#timezoneform").validate({
    rules: {
        timezone_selector: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        timezone_selector: {
            required: "You must select a timezone"
        }
    }

});
});
</script>
</head>
```

How can I get a similar message to appear for select statements as `validate()` does for text boxes.  I've seen posts like this but I'm still having no luck.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/7atKS/

Comment: Weird...no idea why it doesn't work on my page...

Comment: Well I have a few ideas, but for some reason I can't get the message to show up properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form need a few tweaks:

```
<form id="timezoneform" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>" method="POST">

    <select name="DropDownTimezone" id="DropDownTimezone">
      <option selected="" name="timezone_selector" value="" style="font-style:italic">Please select a timezone</option>
      <option value="Pacific/Midway">Pacific/Midway (GMT -11:00)</option>
      ....
      </select>
    <input type="submit" id="changetimezone" name="changetimezone" value="Change timezone" />
</form>
```

Note specifically that:

- the `option` element should not have a `name` attribute, and the `validate` plugin should not be targeting the `option` element.
- You also don't need `class='required'` on the `select` if you're going to define the rule in your JavaScript.
- Finally, you don't need to call `validate` inside a `click` handler. You can define it as soon as the form is ready (`js(document).ready(function () { ... });`).

In summary:

```
var js = jQuery.noConflict();
js(document).ready(function() {
    js("#timezoneform").validate({
        rules: {
            DropDownTimezone: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            DropDownTimezone: {
                required: "You must select a timezone"
            }
        }

    });
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ALUQB/

Comment: Oh dear, I can't believe I forgot `js(document).ready(function () { ... });`. Thanks!  Just need to figure out the css for this to put the message in the right place.

Comment: @TomPepernic: Glad to help! The only thing I couldn't quite figure out is how to get your custom message **"Please select a timezone"** to show. This may actually be a bug in jQuery validate. I'll do some more digging

Answer (score 0):

you need to require the `select` list not the option value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var js = jQuery.noConflict();
js("#changetimezone").click(function() {
js("#timezoneform").validate({
    rules: {
        DropDownTimezone: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        DropDownTimezone: {
            required: "You must select a timezone"
        }
    }

});
});
</script>
```

This works because your value on the `timezone_selector` is set to an empty string.  It will now give you the correct error message.  If you need help with placement look into the `errorPlacement`, `errorContainer`, and `errorElement` options found here [jQuery Validate Options](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions)